# JQuery script doesn't get called accurately with the dropdownlist mvc

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the first time im posting a question here. I am new to mvc.
I want to develop two cascading dropdown lists. I am using mvc4. Here what i have done.

Factory class

```
public class Factory
{
    [Key]
    public int FactoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string FactoryCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string FactoryName { get; set; }

    public int City { get; set; }

    public int Country { get; set; }
```

I have Country and City classes separately with a foreign key relationship

City class

```
public  class City
{

   [Key]
   public int CityId { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
   public string CityCode { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
   public string CityName { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Country")]
   public int CountryId { get; set; }
   public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Country class

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<City> cities { get; set; }
}
```

Factory controller

```
public ActionResult FactoryIndex(string A, int? Id, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();

        if (A == "New")
        {
            var model = new Factory();
            ViewData["mdl"] = model;
            ViewBag.CountryList = objContext.Countries;
            ViewBag.Module = A;


        }
.....................
```

Rendering the partialview within the IndexView

```
@if (ViewBag.Module != null)
    {
        if (ViewBag.Module == "New")
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Masters/Views/Factory/_FactoryCreate.cshtml", ViewData["mdl"]);
        }
```

_FactoryCreate partial view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.Country,new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName"), "Select country", new {id="CountryId", @class = "form-control"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.City; a.City, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "CityId", "CityName"), "Select city", new {@class = "form-control" })
```

jquery script within the partialview

```
$(function() {

            $('#CountryId').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Factory/FillCity/',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { Country: countryId },
                    success: function (cities) {
                        $("#City").html("");
                        $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                            $("#City").append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
                        });
                    }
                });
            })
        })
```

ActionResult in FactoryController that fetches the relevant City data

```
public ActionResult FillCity(int country)
{
    var db = new KnittingdbContext();
    var cities = db.Cities.Where(c =>c.CountryId == country);
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Country dropdownlist is working.
But the City DDL is not working. The data doesn't get binded.
When the `CountryId` gets changed it comes to jquery script. i could recognize it using a Alert. But after the URL property in script it doesn't work.

Success method is not getting executed. I think the issue is with the way i present the url. I tried it with different ways. But still couldn't get it solved.  These views and controllers are in a Area.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never declare or assign a value to `countryId`so `country` in the controller would be null.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for the reply. As you said i tried to assign a value to countryId. I did it like this. data{Country:country}. But it didn't work. Then i changed it to data{Country:countryId=CountryId}. But Still doesn't work. I thought that the countryId get assigned by a value after the first ddl value got changed while selecting an item from ddl and then it is sent to the controller method as a parameter. Pls help..

Comment: You have a few other issues in your code as well. Can you post the model for `City` (as returned by `db.Cities`) - may as well fix them all for you :)

Comment: Ok as you said i added the City and the Country classes above and have improved the code :)

Comment: Your parameter Country in data and the parameter you passed in FillCity does not match.One has capitalized character.Is it intentional?

Comment: @user238905, The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive - you could use `cOUntRy` and it would still work.

Comment: Ok Stephen didn't know that.thnx for correction.Also I notice OP is returning ActionResult,shouldn't it be JsonResult.

Comment: @user238905, `JsonResult` is `ActionResult` so does not really matter, but explicitly specifying `JsonResult` is always better IMHO

Comment: @user238905, earier i used data{country:CountryId} which matches to the parameter in the FillCity.But the issue remained unsolved.

Comment: @Isuru, be patient - answer will be added in a moment :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thank you. I am looking forward for your relpy while trying:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not passing the selected value of the first dropdown to your controller method so it would throw an exception (`country` is typeof `int` and cannot be `null`). Your script should be (note its unclear why you would change the `id` attribute from `id="Country"` to `id="CountryId"` by using `new { id="CountryId" }` so this example uses the default

```
var cityDropdown = $("#City"); // cache it to avoid repeatedly searching the DOM
$('#Country').change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "Factory")', // dont hard code your url's
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { Country: $(this).val() }, // pass the selected value
    success: function (cities) {
        cityDropdown.empty();
        $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
            cityDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
        });
    }
});
```

of more simply

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("FillCity", "Factory")', { Country: $(this).val() }, function(cities){
    cityDropdown.empty();
    ... 
});
```

Note also your method is serializing all properties of typeof `City` including `CityCode`, `CountryId` and `Country` (and all the properries of `Country`) which you never use so this is a waste of bandwidth and just degrades performance (and has the potential to cause a circular reference exception). Change your method to

```
public JsonResult FillCity(int country)
{
    var db = new KnittingdbContext();
    var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CountryId == country).Select(c => new
    {
      CityId = c.CityId,
      CityName = c.CityName
    };
    return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note also there are other issues with your code, for example if you have validation errors and return the view in the POST method, the city dropdown list will not be populated, forcing the user to re-select it all over again. Suggest you start using view models and review the code in this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: thanks :) I am going to try it in your way. Once im done i will let you know the result.

Comment: ok i have put my working solution below. The issue was with the script i suppose. Finally i got it worked. You gave me some good tips. Thanks again:)

Comment: @  Stephen Muecke, I had to change the script, as an ex type: 'POST' instead of 'GET' and i had to change parameter type of FillCity to string. Otherwise it gave me internal 500 error. I found these things considering your instructions. I thought to help someone new to this like me with the little knowledge i gained up to now. That's why i put that answer.

Comment: You should not be changing it to POST (because your not changing data so it should be a GET). And you don't need to change it to `string` because property `CountryId` is type `int` so clearly you still have numerous thing to learn or are still making mistakes. And your code still shows you return a `SelectList` which is pointless extra overhead. And your script has logic errors, e.g. how could `if (countrySelected == "")` ever be entered - because in the preceding line your set it to `0` if `countrySelected == ""`!

Comment: ok i got those points now. Thank you. After some research i changed the solution because i couldn't get it worked.  All your instructions are valuable for me. i ll develop it again considering your points and let you know the result.

Comment: I gave you a link to a working example in the answer showing how it all should be done. Study it :)

Comment: yes. thanks. I'll study it and redevelop the solution. I'll let you know the result :)

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot :) Ealier i developed it based on your instructions(but without viewmodel, don't know whether it is the reason) and it gave me internal server 500 error and again  after some changes 404 error. So i changed it to another script and a json funcion and it started working(The code i put). Now again i developed it in your way(with viewwmodel) and it is working perfectly. Still can't figureout where i went wrong. I removed my code because your approch is simple, perfect and very clear. Again thanks alot :)